# Implementing 2D Torus Array with Haskell's Repa

Tags: arrays, haskell, boundary, repa

I just started looking at Repa and would like to know how to best implement a wrap-around, torus style 2D array read/written by stencil operation. I implemented this before using the ST monad and mutable vectors, but it seems this is not supported by Repa. A few approaches seem possible:

- I could just 'traverse' the array and do the index wrapping myself at each element. For simple stencils the cost of applying the wrapping logic everywhere is quite severe, so I'd need to avoid this one
- Data.Array.Repa.Stencil doesn't support the boundary condition I need, but looks like Data.Array.Repa.Algorithms.Convolve does. Documentation suggests a heavy performance penalty, though
- From what I understand, I can traverse over a subset of the array using slices. So, I could define an interior (1, 1) - (w-2, h-2), two horizontal and two vertical slabs representing the boundary, and then traverse them using two different functions / stencils, resulting in a single result array? Any sample code or further documentation on this?
- Repa also seems to have the concept of 'partitions', can they be used for implementing boundary conditions?

Which one is likely to be fastest? Any options I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way is to employ `Partitioned` array representation (your 4th option), however, it is inconvenient, because you should work with [5 areas](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/repa/3.2.3.3/doc/html/Data-Array-Repa-Stencil-Dim2.html#t%3aPC5) by hand.

In [Yarr](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yarr/1.3.2/doc/html/Data-Yarr-Convolution.html#v%3aconvolveShDim2WithStaticStencil) you could write an utility

```
dim2WrapAround :: USource r l Dim2 a => UArray r l Dim2 a -> Dim2 -> Dim2 -> IO a
{-# INLINE dim2WrapAround #-}
dim2WrapAround arr (sizeX, sizeY) (posX, posY) =
    index arr (wrap sizeX posX, wrap sizeY posY)
  where wrap size pos = (pos + size) `mod` size

-- I'm afraid to write the signature...
{-# INLINE convolveOnThorus #-}
convolveOnThorus = convolveLinearDim2WithStaticStencil dim2WrapAround
```

Usage:

```
myConvolution :: UArray F L Dim2 Float -> UArray CV CVL Dim2 Float
myConvolution = convolveOnThorus [dim2St| some
                                           coeffs
                                               here |]
```

Comment: Would convolveLinearDim2WithStaticStencil only use dim2WrapAround at the borders where the stencil can go out of bounds or at every element? It looks to me like this is basically the the same as ConvolveP from Data.Array.Repa.Algorithms.Convolve? (Clever wrapping logic, btw. I'd have done it with two branches or a modulo, nice!)

Comment: @AN1 only at the borders. No, name convolveDim2With*Static*Stencil designates it is really static, even faster than static stencil convolution from Repa 3, indeed.

Comment: @AN1 also my "clever" wrapping was wrong... Decided modulo is still better here. See the edit to the answer.

Comment: Ok, I get it, and it supports arbitrary boundary conditions, unlike the Repa stencils which force me to use dynamic ones. Yet another library to check out! Just looking at Repa, do you know of any good example code etc. for Slices/Partitions? The official documentation is a bit sparse and the Parallel Haskell book and Haskell.org tutorial don't seem to explain them ;-(

Comment: @AN1 Slices don't suit for this task for sure. Explore the implementation of stencils: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/repa/3.2.3.3/doc/html/src/Data-Array-Repa-Stencil-Dim2.html#mapStencil2

Comment: Oh, just saw the '-- Partition the array into the internal and border regions' part, brilliant, thanks!